# Linting jsx-a11y adding role to div element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint

I am having trouble with [no-static-element-interactions](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-static-element-interactions.md)

Here is my code that doesn't pass it

```
      <div
        className={ `selector-button ${ displayType === "GRID" && "active" }` }
        onClick={ this.handleClick.bind( this, "GRID" ) }
        role="button"
      >
```

Even adding a `role="button"` can't help me to pass through.

Comment: maybe this s related to https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/214 ?

Comment: thank you very much. So hope they will close the issue soon, For now I just set it to 'warnings'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is related to https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/214 issue on eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y plugin repo.

Please follow the conversation their.